# Should one invest in smaller valued shares in higher amounts, or higher valued shares in smaller amounts?

Tags: stocks, investing, shares, investment-strategies, profitability

For example, would one be wise to start off with the big guns (like Google, which has shares worth north of $800 U.S.D.) -- or start with the babies (like Monster, Fox, or any others worth < $100)?

I am wondering if there's any difference in strategy, profitability, or anything else that should be known when deciding between a bigger split of lesser valued shares of companies or smaller split of bigger.

Comment: Would you like to change / edit your question, from the focus on share price to total market capitalization? The latter is far more important when investing.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I don't think this person knows the difference and that's really what the questions is really about.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No, it only matters if you want to use covered calls strategies.
The price of a share is not important. Some companies make [stock splits](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stocksplit.asp) from time to time so that the price of their shares is more affordable to small investors. It is **a decision of the company's board** to keep the price high or low. More important is the capitalization for these shares.

If you have lots of money to invest, the best is to divide and invest a fixed pourcentage of your portfolio in each company you choose.

The only difference is if you eventually decide to use covered call strategies. To have a buy write on Google will cost you a lot of money and you will only be able to sell 1 option for every 100 shares.
**Bottom line:** the **price is not important, [capitalization](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketcapitalization.asp) and estimated earnings are**. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a case to be made that companies below a certain market cap have more potential than the higher ones.

Consider, Apple cannot grow 100 fold from its current value. At $700B or so in value, that would be a $70T goal, just about the value of all the combined wealth in the entire US. At some point, the laws of large numbers take over, and exponential growth starts to flatten out.

On the flip side, Apple may have as good or better chance to rise 10% over the next 6-12 months as a random small cap stock.